# Does Android TV require always-on internet access?

Tags: android-tv

(this is not actually a dev question though it starts out sounding like one)

I've been working on a Chromecast app that functions mainly as a display of information that it gets from other devices on a network.  But internet access wasn't needed for any functionality except to load the Chromecast app which meant we couldn't use it at all in places there was power, WiFi networks, but no internet access.

Enter Android TV and the Nexus Player.  It seems to allow for actual installations rather than just pulling down a webpage for each running.  Is this accurate?  Does it require an always-on connection or else it shuts down?  Or does it work like phones/tablets when they lose access allowing things like local-only games to run without problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes on Android TV I can play local games without Internet.

Comment: You should get a demo from the store to be assured, don't trust my word :)